# Is there a category similar to Set, but having the morphism binary relations instead of functions?

Tags: category-theory

I call this hypotetic category BigSet. The definition of BigSet is:

- Objects are sets
- Morphisms are binary relations (including functions)
- Composition is the composition of relations
- Identities are the identity functions

Functions are special binary relations, so this category differs from Set only that in BigSet there are more morphisms than in Set. Am I right that this is a category? Is it used in mathematics? I yes, where, if not, why?

Comment: I just want to add the note that while in one sense there are more morphisms in $\mathbf{Rel}$ than $\mathbf{Set}$, it's also the case that $\mathbf{Rel}$ is equivalent to what's called the Kliesli category on the covariant powerset monad. What that means is that all the morphisms in $\mathbf{Rel}$ can be viewed as a subclass of functions in $\mathbf{Set}$ equipped with a different composition operation.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, these have been considered.  There is a whole research monograph around this theme, Categories and Allegories by Freyd and Scedrov.

The nLab has an entry on the category you define, which it calls [Rel](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/Rel).  (The page is written with one eye towards n-category theory, so it's a bit heavy on the terminology.)

Categories like Rel have extra properties that can be exploited.  Categories with these extra properties are called [allegories](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/allegory).